# Python dictionary value conversion to dictionary list

Tags: python

```
class Weightcheck:

def bag_products(self,product_list):
    bag_list = []
    non_bag_items = []
    MAX_BAG_WEIGHT = 5.0

    for product in product_list:
        if float(product['weight']) > MAX_BAG_WEIGHT:
            product_list.remove(product)
            non_bag_items.append(product)
```

and argument product_list is like

```
product_list = {'barcode': [123, 456], 'Name': ['Milk, 2 Litres', 'Bread'], 'Price': ['2', '3.5'], 'weight': ['2', '0.6']}
```

if the passed arugument is like

```
product_list = [{'name': 'Milk', 'price': 2.0, 'weight': 2.0},
            {'name': 'LowfatMilk', 'price': 2.0, 'weight': 2.0},
            {'name': 'HighfatMilk', 'price': 2.0, 'weight': 2.0},
            {'name': 'Bread', 'price': 2.0, 'weight': 7.0}]
```

then it works properly. i mean list of dictionary. please help how can i solve this

Comment: What did you try? Please post your code. Also, fix your example: it is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best way but you can use something like this:

```
final_list = [] 
for i in range(len(product_in_basket['Name'])):
    item ={} # each new item
    for k,v in product_in_basket.items():
        item[k]= v[i] # filling that item with specific index
    final_list.append(item) # append to final list

> final_list
[
  {'Name': 'Milk, 2 Litres', 'Price': '2', 'barcode': 123, 'weight': '2.0'},
  {'Name': 'Bread', 'Price': '3.5', 'barcode': 456, 'weight': '0.6'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that does the trick:

```
product_list = [dict(zip(product_in_basket,t)) for t in zip(*product_in_basket.values())]

print(product_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'Milk, 2 Litres', 'Price': '2', 'barcode': 123, 'weight': '2.0'}, {'Name': 'Bread', 'Price': '3.5', 'barcode': 456, 'weight': '0.6'}]
```

In general, it's better to not use a library when plain Python will do, but I thought a solution using pandas might be interesting:

```
import pandas as pd

product_in_basket = {'barcode': [123, 456], 'Name': ['Milk, 2 Litres', 'Bread'],
                 'Price': ['2', '3.5'], 'weight': ['2.0', '0.6']}

df = pd.DataFrame(product_in_basket)

output = list(df.T.to_dict().values())

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'Milk, 2 Litres', 'Price': '2', 'barcode': 123, 'weight': '2.0'},
 {'Name': 'Bread', 'Price': '3.5', 'barcode': 456, 'weight': '0.6'}]
```